# What is the most compact way in JavaScript to sort an array of objects by a particular key, where the sorting order is defined in an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Here's what I mean. Suppose I have an array of objects like

```
var objs = [ { foo: 5, bar: "something"}, 
             { foo: 4912, bar: "blah" }, 
             { foo: -12, bar: "hehe" } ];
```

and an array that defines an ordering on `bar` values, like

```
var arr = ["blah", "something", "hehe"]
```

Does JavaScript have a good way of getting a version of `objs` to

```
[ { foo: 4912, bar: "blah" }, 
  { foo: 5, bar: "something"}
  { foo: -12, bar: "hehe" } ];
```

???

The best way I know is like

```
objs.sort(function(x,y){
    var ix = arr.indexOf(x), 
        iy = arr.indexOf(y);
    if(ix<iy) return -1;
    else if(ix==iy) return 0;
    else return 1;
});
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way that is more compact.

Answer (score 5):

You can slightly refactor sort function:

```
objs.sort(function(x,y){
    var ix = arr.indexOf(x), 
        iy = arr.indexOf(y);
    return ix-iy;
});
```

Also, for better performance you may want to get rid of indexOf functions, and load sort array into hash:

```
var arr = {
    "blah" :0,
    "something":1,
     "hehe":2};
```

And sorting function will look like this:

```
objs.sort(function(x,y){
    return arr[x.bar]-arr[y.bar];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The kind of sort you're wanting to do would go something like:

```
function inArray(v, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function weirdSort(objsArray, objProperty, useArray){
  var r = [], c = [];
  for(var i=0,l=obsArray.length; i<l; i++){
    var o = objsArray[i];
    if(inArray(o[objProperty], useArray)){
      r.push(o);
    }
    else{
      c.push(o);
    }
  }
  return r.concat(c);
}
var result = weirdSort(obs, 'bar', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither your original function, nor the code at the top of the currently accepted answer, actually sorts correctly.  You need to reference the `bar` property in your sort function.

Try this:

```
var sortFunc = (ar,p) => (a,b) => ar.indexOf(a[p]) - ar.indexOf(b[p])

objs.sort(sortFunc(arr,"bar"))
```

Using a higher-order function gives you the flexibility to use any reference array you want, not one just named `arr`, and to sort based on any property in your objects, not just one named `bar`.